# Passing form action into a Jade template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a Jade template with an HTML form on it.  The action of the form is conditional and depends on information outside the Jade template, so I want to pass it in.  How do I do that? Code snippet:

ExpressJS app:

```
    router.get('/report', function(req, resp) {
      resp.render('report_template', { 
        'formAction': 'http://reporting.server.com/report1/' 
        });
    });
```

Jade template:

```
form(id="report", name="report", action=formAction, method="post")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form(id="report", name="report", action="#{formAction}", method="post")
```

You need to use `#{}` to access variables in jade templates.

Comment: Within the form that gives me an "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error.  It's passing it correctly though, because preceding that line with "p #{formAction}" outputs the action in a <p> tag as expected.

Comment: My bad, you need to quote it.
form(id="report", name="report", action="#{formAction}", method="post")

Answer (score 0):

Caution
Previous versions of Pug/Jade supported an interpolation syntax such as:

a(href="/#{url}") Link
This syntax is no longer supported. Alternatives are found below. (Check our migration guide for more information on other incompatibilities between Pug v2 and previous versions.)

https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).